# Sklearn SequentialFeatureSelector "Pipeline should either be a classifier" when using a classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-selection, mlxtend

I get this error when using a classifier and SFS as a part of sklearn pipeline:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 45, in <module>
    rs.fit(X_train, y_train)
  File "/home/runner/SFSpredictproba/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 1151, in wrapper
    return fit_method(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/SFSpredictproba/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py", line 898, in fit
    self._run_search(evaluate_candidates)
  File "/home/runner/SFSpredictproba/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py", line 1419, in _run_search
    evaluate_candidates(ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))
  File "/home/runner/SFSpredictproba/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py", line 845, in evaluate_candidates
    out = parallel(
  File "/home/runner/SFSpredictproba/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/parallel.py", line 65, in __call__
    return super().__call__(iterable_with_config)
  File "/home/runner/SFSpredictproba/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 1855, in __call__
    return output if self.return_generator else list(output)
  File "/home/runner/SFSpredictproba/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 1784, in _get_sequential_output
    res = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/SFSpredictproba/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/parallel.py", line 127, in __call__
    return self.function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/SFSpredictproba/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 754, in _fit_and_score
    test_scores = _score(estimator, X_test, y_test, scorer, error_score)
  File "/home/runner/SFSpredictproba/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 813, in _score
    scores = scorer(estimator, X_test, y_test)
  File "/home/runner/SFSpredictproba/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_scorer.py", line 266, in __call__
    return self._score(partial(_cached_call, None), estimator, X, y_true, **_kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/SFSpredictproba/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_scorer.py", line 459, in _score
    y_pred = method_caller(clf, "decision_function", X, pos_label=pos_label)
  File "/home/runner/SFSpredictproba/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_scorer.py", line 86, in _cached_call
    result, _ = _get_response_values(
  File "/home/runner/SFSpredictproba/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_response.py", line 103, in _get_response_values
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Pipeline should either be a classifier to be used with response_method=decision_function or the response_method should be 'predict'. Got a regressor with response_method=decision_function instead.
```

Code to reproduce ([replit](https://replit.com/@charlie421/SFSpredictproba#main.py)):

```
clf = LogisticRegression()
cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=2)
sfs = SFS(clf, n_features_to_select=1, scoring='accuracy', cv=cv, n_jobs=-1)
imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='median')
lr_param_grid = {
  'sequentialfeatureselector__estimator__class_weight': ['balanced', None]
}
pipe = make_pipeline(imputer, sfs)
rs = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe,
                  param_grid=lr_param_grid,
                  cv=cv,
                  scoring="roc_auc",
                  error_score="raise")

# Generate random data for binary classification
X, y = make_classification(
  n_samples=10,  # Number of samples
  n_features=3,  # Number of features
  n_informative=2,  # Number of informative features
  n_redundant=1,  # Number of redundant features
  n_clusters_per_class=1,  # Number of clusters per class
  random_state=42)

# Split the data into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

rs.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I get the same error when using other classifiers, other performance metrics, and when using `mlxtend` version of SFS.

Versions of packages:

- python = 3.10.8
- scikit-learn = 1.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're encountering stems from an interaction between the `Sequential Feature Selector`, `GridSearchCV`, and the scoring method being used.

`GridSearchCV` validates your model using cross-validation internally. For some scoring methods, such as `'roc_auc'`, it requires class probabilities provided by the model. These probabilities are typically obtained via the `predict_proba()` or `decision_function()` methods from the classifier.

However, the SFS does not expose these methods from the classifier it encapsulates. As a result, when `GridSearchCV` attempts to apply the scoring function `'roc_auc'`, it encounters an error because it cannot access the required probability estimates.

Similarly, if you change the scoring function to `'accuracy'` or others that rely on the `predict()` method, you may face another issue since SFS does not expose the `predict()` method from the encapsulated classifier.

This is the root cause of the error message you're seeing - a lack of access to required methods due to the encapsulation of the classifier within the SFS.

As for `mlxtend`, it seems probable that you're encountering the same issue. If `mlxtend`'s `Sequential Feature Selector` also does not expose the `predict_proba()`, `decision_function()`, or `predict()` methods from the encapsulated classifier, you would face a similar problem.

Comment: Thanks, what's the proper way to use SFS with grid search in this case?

Comment: Perform SFS separately before GridSearchCV. Use the selected features in GridSearchCV with the classifier directly

Comment: I guess you wanted to have the number of features as a hyperparameter in your grid search? In that case, you might want to follow my previous advice and start your script multiple times with a different number of features on each run